# Loading the same PHP file from a subdomain with an indicator

Tags: php

I have a top level domain where my main site is located.
I want to create a subdomain for translation (e.g. "spanish.MyDomain.com ") so all the text would be in Spanish (I use a PHP translator for that purpose).

How can I load my index.php file located in my main site's directory from the subdomain with a different version (i.e. a variable indicating the version should be in Spanish). 
An alternative would be just to copy the index.php to the new "spanish" directory created on the server, but that would be a massive code duplication.

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure all subdomains to point at the same folder and use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to figure out which language to use.